# Leaflet Realtime popup

Tags: leaflet, popup

Hello how can i get shown popups on my marks using [Realtime](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime) showing the "name" from results.geojson? So that when i click one it says e.g VW and on another one e.g BMW.

```
var map = L.map('map'),
    realtime = L.realtime('results.geojson', {
    interval: 3 * 1000,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            'icon': L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'car.png',
                iconSize:     [50, 50], // size of the icon
                popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            })
        });
        
    }
    
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: When you say "_get shown popups_", do you mean the popup should be displayed by default, or on user click on the Marker?

Comment: When the user clicks it then it should appear my mistake for bad desc.